# Resample NAudio WaveIn microphone input from 8000 to 44100 kHz

Tags: c#, naudio, resampling

I'm writing educational musical app for my students.

I need to pass audio input to pitchAnalyzer; It works fine with 44100 samplerate but showing wrong results with 8000.

I read a lot of examples: how that can be done reading and writing to the file. But i don't have file to read and don't need to write audio.

I already did conversion from 16 bit byte array to IEEE float ( format that pitchAnalyzer algorithm requires) which comes with the **WaveInOnDataAvailable** event;

```
void WaveInOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)

var buffer = waveInEventArgs.Buffer;
float[] samples = new float[buffer.Length/2];       

for (int n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n += 2)
{
    samples[n / 2] = BitConverter.ToInt16(resampled_buffer, n) / 32768f;
}
```

WaveIn setup:

```
waveIn = new WaveIn();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = comboBx_RecordingDevices.SelectedIndex;  
waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveInOnDataAvailable;
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

1. So how this can be resampled directly to the buffer without writing it to a file?
2. Is there is a way to change WaveIn input samplerate? Property shows that it can't be set, but probably there is another way?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Something manually reading in every 44,100 / 8,000 cycles and averaging them into 1 sample?  Roughly read in 5 samples and average and save to buffer, read in 6 samples and average and save to buffer, repeat?

Comment: As far as i understand, you mean to implement interpolation manually. This should work but i know that there are several algorythms that implement it including anti-aliasing. I just can't find the code where they used without reading and writing to the file.

Comment: Can you not read the whole file into a buffer, do the work, than write it all an once (or just use it and skip the write)?  I assumed you were trying to fight against a ton of small read/writes hurting performance, but if this is not correct, please correct me.

Comment: I'd also add that there seems to be quite a few open source projects using naudio that may show you, in action, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: 1) That's the point: I DON'T READ audio data from file. I get the buffer from microphone. For most of the "resamplers" - they do read data from file, they require input file in their interface. 2) I DON't read audio to the file. Again, all resamplers i've seen in examples, etc. use output file. I don't have one, i need to pass it to pitchAnalyzer which is part of the program. 3) The question is: how to use "resamplers" avoiding file reading and writing. Or if there is a way to imitate file reading\writing to use them in a tricky way.

Comment: Got it.  The first thought that comes to mind is to look closer at the naudio files and see how easy it would be to expose the resampler algorithms.  I'd expect them to be reasonaby segregated into "read file", "resample", "write file" internally, so it may just be you would need to expose the resample part.  You might even be able to submit such a change to the open source community so that it could benefit others.

Comment: Went and downloaded NAudio.  At least for the wav reader class, it take either a string FileName or a "Stream" for input.  I strongly suspect all the other forms are the same.  So you should be able to pass your buffer as a stream with into the class.